# How to distort an image by noise in p5.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to produce a function that starts with source image, generates noise, and then uses the noise to distort the image.
I start with creating the noise, and turning it into a vector field, Then I remap the coordinates, and pull the pixels out of the image at the correct coordinates.
Finally I re-combine the extracted pixels into an image.

So far my code is as follows:

```js
function distort(sourceImage){
  let vectorField = [];
  var amount = 100;
  var scale = 0.01;
  for (x = 0; x < sourceImage.width; x++){
    let row = [];
    for (y = 0; y < sourceImage.height; y++){
      let vector = createVector(amount*(noise(scale*x,scale*y)-0.5), 4*amount*(noise(100+scale*x,scale*y)-0.5))
      row.push(vector);
    }
    vectorField.push(row);
  }

  var result = [];
  sourceImage.loadPixels();
  for (i = 0; i < sourceImage.width; i++){ //sourceImage.width
    for (j = 0; j < sourceImage.height; j += 4){ //sourceImage.height
      var res = vectorField[i][j];
      //console.log(res);

      var ii = constrain(floor(i + res.x), 0, sourceImage.width - 1);
      var jj = constrain(floor(j + res.y), 0, sourceImage.height - 1);
      //console.log(ii, jj);

      result[i * sourceImage.width + j] = color(sourceImage.pixels[ii * sourceImage.width + jj], sourceImage.pixels[ii * sourceImage.width + jj + 1], sourceImage.pixels[ii * sourceImage.width + jj + 2], sourceImage.pixels[ii * sourceImage.width + jj + 3]);
    }
  }
  //console.log(result)
  //console.log(sourceImage.pixels[0 + sourceImage.width * 0])

  for (n=0; n<sourceImage.width; n++) {
    for(m=0; m<sourceImage.height; m++){
      index = (n * sourceImage.width + m) * 4;
      if (index >= 4194300){
        index = 4194300;
      }
      sourceImage.pixels[index] = red(result[index]);
      sourceImage.pixels[index + 1] = green(result[index]);
      sourceImage.pixels[index + 2] = blue(result[index]);
      sourceImage.pixels[index + 3] = alpha(result[index]);
    }
  }


  sourceImage.updatePixels();
  image(sourceImage, 0, 0, size, size);
}
```

Except that as a result, I'm getting 4 panels of noise across the top 4th of the canvas. The noise notably includes a lot of pixels that I know weren't in the source image, too (namely blue pixels; the image I'm trying to distort is red and white). The noise is sort of identifiable as having started as the source image, but distorted and with the aforementioned artefacts.

For comparison:

[image: original]
[image: results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not process the vector field completely, you have to read each vector from the field. Actually you read just each 4th element of the vector

<s>`for (j = 0; j < sourceImage.height; j += 4)`</s>

```js
for (j = 0; j < sourceImage.height; j++)
```

Further the computation of the source index is wrong. Note the control variable for the row (`jj`) has to be multiplied by the height. The index of the pixel in the array has to be multiplied by 4, because each pixel consists of 4 color channels:

<s>`ii * sourceImage.width + jj`</s>

```js
(jj * sourceImage.width + ii) * 4
```

The computation of the target index is wrong, too:

<s>`index = (n * sourceImage.width + m) * 4;`</s>

```js
index = (m * sourceImage.width + n) * 4;
```

Note, `result` contains 1 element for each pixel, byut `sourceImage.pixels` contains 4 elements for each pixel. Thus the index which reads from result and the index which access the target are different:

```js
let result_i = m * sourceImage.width + n;
let target_i = result_i * 4;
```

For instance:

```js
let result = [];
for (let j = 0; j < sourceImage.height; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < sourceImage.width; i++) {

      let res = vectorField[i][j];

      let ii = constrain(floor(i + res.x), 0, sourceImage.width - 1);
      let jj = constrain(floor(j + res.y), 0, sourceImage.height - 1);

      let source_i = (jj * sourceImage.width + ii) * 4;
      let col = color(
          sourceImage.pixels[source_i],
          sourceImage.pixels[source_i + 1],
          sourceImage.pixels[source_i + 2],
          sourceImage.pixels[source_i + 3]);

      result.push(col);
    }
}

for(let m = 0; m < sourceImage.height; m++) {
    for (let n = 0; n < sourceImage.width; n++) {

        let result_i = m * sourceImage.width + n;
        let target_i = result_i * 4;

        let col = result[result_i];
        sourceImage.pixels[target_i]     = red(col);
        sourceImage.pixels[target_i + 1] = green(col);
        sourceImage.pixels[target_i + 2] = blue(col);
        sourceImage.pixels[target_i + 3] = alpha(col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly except for 1 thing: the resulting image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I really don't understand why - think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @YodraGurl Sorry, my bad. You've to swap `for (let j = 0; j < sourceImage.height; j++)` and `for (let i = 0; i < sourceImage.width; i++)`. Else `result` would be generated in the wrong order and that causes that the image is rotated. I've changed that in the answer.